# Connect to MongoDB from Spring Boot Application over SSL

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I use the following adjustments for local development in the application.properties:

```
myproject.mongodb.databaseName=databaseName
myproject.mongodb.databaseAddress=serverName.mycompany.at
myproject.mongodb.databasePort=27017
myproject.mongodb.username=myProjectName
myproject.mongodb.password=asdfasdf
myproject.mongodb.mappingBasePackage=domain
```

Now I will use the app in a productiv way and therefore need SSL like I can adjust with RoboMongo:

[image: RoboMongo Param]

Does anyone know what I have to set in my application.properties file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to connect with options (without extra code) is to use the connection string/uri. It would look something like this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://myProjectName:asdfasdf@serverName.mycompany.at:27017/databaseName?ssl=true
```